# Some clarification of GAE Blobstore's create_upload_url()

Tags: google-app-engine, django-admin, blobstore

I am using the GAE Blobstore to upload and serve images for my Django app. For admin users maintenance is available by wrapping the image in a Django model `Image` and supplying the standard admin features for this model: add, update, delete.

To perform the actual upload, I modified the `change_form.html` template for the Image model and replaced `{{ form_url }}` with `{{ blobstore_url}}`. `{{ blobstore_url }}` gets set by overriding the `render_change_form` of `ImageAdmin`.

I noticed that by by calling `create_upload_url("/admin/some/url")`, I get an encoded url to GAE Blobstore's upload facility and the argument of the function ("/admin/some/url") is actually the url to which GAE/Blobstore redirects upon completion of the upload.

Not really relevant to question, but something I noticed as well is that in my first approach I just overwrote the value of `{{ form_url }}` but that does not seem to work as the form's action was not set; it either gets overwritten somewhere else or is ignored.

Although this works the main downside is that this approach requires me to implement "admin/some/url" as a view from where I can process the required add or change of the model Image, which really is duplication of code as the default admin already supports these features.

So my question is what would be the correct url to pass to `create_upload_url()` in order to run the standard admin functionality of validation and database update for the Image model after completion of the upload?

**EDIT**

Alternatively, it might be a better design to perform the upload after the default admin operation (e.g. insert or update) have completed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd pass in the admin URL where the form normally posts to to create_upload_url().

This way the file will upload to Blobstore, then the form will be redirected to the normal admin form processing url.

However, this won't "just work", unless you're using django-nonrel.  In the redirect destination, you need to save the GAE blobstore url into your model, which doesn't happen by default with django.  If you want to do it this way, you can look into integrating django-nonrel's GAE storage backend.

https://github.com/dragonx/djangoappengine/blob/1.4-devappserver2/djangoappengine/storage.py

Comment: Thanks. I already found the requirement for non-rel storage.py which I have integrated in my project. What if I want to do the upload AFTER the normal admin processing. Is that possible?

Comment: This is probably possible, but I doubt you want to go down this road.  You'll have to handle the actual upload in normal admin POST request.  In that case you'll have to make a new storage.py upload handler that'll write the uploaded file to the blobstore using the blobstore file API... Or maybe call a urlfetch() to the upload url (it wouldn't work with an HTTP redirect).

Comment: Ok, clear. Could you maybe give an example of how I obtain the normal form processing url for a model in the admin, say MyModel and the add operation to add an instance of MyModel...?